# Conflicting java script sine waves in html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a first time poster here and an absolute newbie on coding, so please bear with me on this doubt.

I'm programming a website for myself and I want to add an animated java script sine wave (based on superHi's tutorial on the matter). Everything is fine when I add the script with the first wave on the HTML file, but when I add the second script (with different parameters, so I can generate a different wave), the second script just doesn't work.

I already added id's to the elements I want to be affected by the script but that's not fixing my problem. Anyway, here is the HTML part of the code:

```
<body>

  <section class="wave1">
    <svg class="wave1">
      <path id="wave1" class="wave1" d="M10,10 L50,100 L90,50"></path>
    </svg>
  </section>

  <section class="wave2">
    <svg class="wave2">
      <path id="wave2" class="wave2" d="M10,10 L50,100 L90,50"></path>
    </svg>
  </section>

  <script src="scripts/wave1.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/wave2.js"></script>

</body>
```

and here are the two different js, the first wave:

```
let xs = []
for (var i = 0; i <= 5000; i++) {
  xs.push(i)
}

let t = 0
function animate() {

  let points = xs.map(x => {
    let y = 25 + 10 * Math.sin((x + t) / 5)
    return [x, y]
  })

  let path = "M" + points.map(p => {
    return p[0] + "," + p[1]
  }).join(" L")

  document.getElementById("wave1").setAttribute("d", path)
  t += 0.8
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}

animate()
```

And the second wave:

```
let vt = []
for (var x = 0; x <= 5000; x++) {
vt.push(x)
}

let w = 0

function animate() {

 let points = vt.map(e => {

   let r = 55 + 35 * Math.sin((e + w) / 15)

   return [e, r]
   })

let path = "M" + points.map(p => {
return p[0] + "," + p[1]
}).join(" L")

document.getElementById("wave2").setAttribute("d", path)

w += 3

requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}

animate()
```

Any help will be truly appreciated,

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you expecting them to do?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'doesn't work'? Are there any errors in the console or is the wave just not moving?

Comment: change the variable names for your second script.

Comment: The first wave is moving and the second wave isn't (it's not animating)

Comment: changing the variable names in the second script resulted in no change

Comment: Ok, changed everything I could change in the second script. Now both waves are different (which is exactly what I wanted) but the first wave isn't animated!